# MySql :- Count duplicate records including foreign key relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables **1.Purchase** Order Table and another is **2.Supplier** Table.
In between them foreign relation is there(**Supplier_id** present in **Purchase Order** Table).

In Purchase order the supplier_id may be duplicate so my requirement is I need Query to count the duplicate supplier_id as well as fetch the supplier name from the supplier table based upon the supplier_id.
[image: Tables]

[image: Query]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply join the supplier table to your result:

```
select supplier_id,count(*) c, supplier_name 
from purchase_order join supplier s on s.id=supplier_id 
group by supplier_id , supplier_name
having c>1
```